# want to make arryList in java

Tags: android, json, list, listview, arraylist

I have data from JSON like
5,7,9
and i want to save in arrayList as
"","","","","",5,"",7,"",9
what should i do?

Comment: I don't understand the problem you're trying to solve here.  What are the exact rules?  What if there are duplicates?  We can only guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to change code like below in main forloop

Change your weeklyDataList like below

```
ArrayList<int[]>weeklyDataList = new ArrayList<int[]>();
```

Code in Forloop

```
    int[] numbers = new int[characters.length()];

    for (int j = 0; j < characters.length(); j++) {
        numbers[j] = Integer.parseInt(characters.getString(j));

    }

    weeklyDataList.add(i,numbers);
```

Comment: i want to store like object on every index

Comment: good answer and now i want to convert every index to integer array 
Like index 0 is 0,1,2,3,4
convert it to integer array
means convert whole array into integer array
Advance thanks brother

Comment: is it possible to store whole object in array instead of strings?
its easy to get whole object and convert it to integer array